# On my wordpress website I am using Contact form 7 and getting his code output on pages I can't find option to remove

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-form-7, contact-form

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'https://revealhm.com/contact/thank-you/';
}, false );
```

Why I am getting this code on each page. I don't have any redirect plugin for contact form 7 or hidden fields. kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in every page, it might be in your footer.php file. If code is not useful you can remove it from footer.php file.